# How Can I change json array values in php and send them to proper html fields using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to take oracle sql query result data and modify them in php and finally send them to output them in different form fields using JQuery, AJAX.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php

$loanid      = (isset($_POST['loanid'])) ? $_POST['loanid'] : "not";
$loan_name   = (isset($_POST['loan_name'])) ? $_POST['loan_name'] : "not";
$description = (isset($_POST['description'])) ? $_POST['description'] : "not";
$amount      = (isset($_POST['amount'])) ? $_POST['amount'] : "not";
$datestring  = (isset($_POST['textdatetimepicker1'])) ? $_POST['textdatetimepicker1'] : "not";
$rate        = (isset($_POST['rate'])) ? $_POST['rate'] : "not";

echo "-starts: ";
echo $loanid;
echo $loan_name;
echo $description;
echo $amount;

$date_arr = explode('/', $datestring);
$date     = date("Y/m/d", strtotime($date_arr[2] . $date_arr[1] . $date_arr[0]));
echo $datestring;
echo $rate;
echo " ends. ";

$conn = oci_connect('himadri', 'himadri', 'cse.du.ac.bd/duais_test');
if (!$conn) {
    trigger_error("Could not connect to database", E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Connection established.";
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, " begin  
                               :result := PKG_PAYROLL.save_loan_type(
                                            '<loan_type>
                                            <loan_id>$loanid</loan_id>                                        
                                            <loan_name>$loan_name</loan_name>
                                            <description>$description</description>
                                            <amount>$amount</amount>    
                                            <date>$date</date>
                                            <rate>$rate</rate>        
                                            </loan_type>'
                                            );                      

                                end;");

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':result', $ru, 5000);
$output = oci_execute($stid);
echo "<br>";
echo " \n SQL Query Result: \n ";
echo $ru;
$string = $ru;
$xml    = simplexml_load_string($string);
$json   = json_encode($xml);
$array  = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

For example, if above query results returns json output like given below:

```
{"status":"success","loan_type":{"loan_id":"123","loan_name":"Bank Loan","description":"FRB Bank Loan","amount":"1250000","date":"2016-01-26","rate":"5.257"}}
```

I want change their values such as:

- change "loan_id":"123" into "loan_id":"456"
- change "loan_name":"Bank Loan" into "loan_name":"Loan 1" etc.

This my HTML and AJAX JQuery code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Record Loan Type Information</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
   </head>
   <body >
      <div class="container"  >
         <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-primary"  >
               <div class="panel-heading" >
                  <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;">Record Loan Type Information</h3>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" >
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="acode">Loan ID:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textloanid" name="loanid"  placeholder="Enter Loan ID">             
                           <span id="errmsg1" class="errmsg"></span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;" >Loan Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                           <input type="text" id="textloan_name" name="loan_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Loan Name" >        
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="dcode">Description:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textdescription" name="description" placeholder="Enter Loan Description">               
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Amount:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                           <input type="text"  id="textamount" name="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Amount" >        
                           <span id="errmsg2" class="errmsg"></span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;" >Sanction Date:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                           <div class="input-group date">
                              <span class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                              </span>   
                              <input type="text"  id='textdatetimepicker1' name="textdatetimepicker1" class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">       
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" style="text-align:right;">Interest Rate:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                           <input type="text" id="textrate" name="rate" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Rate" >       
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                           <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                           <button type="submit" name="editbtn" class="btn btn-success editbtn">Edit</button>
                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Exit</button> 
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </form>
                  <!-- The result Serialize Text Output inside this div -->
                  <div id="serialize">Serialize Text Output: </div>
                  <!-- The result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
                  <div id="result">Text Output: </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var values = $("form").serialize();

         var i=0;
         $("form").on("submit", function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var values = $( this ).serialize();      
            $('#serialize').append(values);  
            $.ajax({
                url: "loan_type_info.php",
                type: "post",
                async:true,
                data: values,
                dataType: 'html',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                success: function(data) {

                    $('#result').append('Response Data:');
                    $('#result').append(data);
                    $('#result').append('<br>');
                    $('#result').prop('loan_id', data.loan_id);
                },

                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });

         });            

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

In the above code, i want to paste json data into proper input fields such as:

- on element with id="textloanid"  paste    data.loan_id   [ is 456
  comes from "loan_id":"456" ]
- on element with id="textloan_name"  paste  data.loan_name    [ is
  "Loan 1" comes from "loan_name":"Loan 1"]

Updates :

```
$('#result').append('Response Data:');
$('#result').append(data);
I got :Response Data:123 Bank Loan FRB Bank Loan 1250000 26/01/2016 12.25

$('#result').append('Response JSON parse:');
data=JSON.parse(data);
$('#result').append(data);  
I got :Response JSON parse: (nothing)
```

How i can do it.please help me on this code.Thanks

Comment: above `$('#result').prop('loan_id', data.loan_id);` add this code `data=JSON.parse(data)`.  then you can access the values using `data.loan_id` or `data.loan_name`

Comment: Thanks @roullie. I did data=JSON.parse(data);
       $('#result').prop('loan_id', data.loan_id); but it did not worked.can you share more.thanks

Comment: it's too broad to answer in comments that's why i put them on the answers

Answer (score 2):

A follow up from the comments.  After parsing the `data` from the server you can now access the values inside `data` and put them wherever you want.

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#result').append('Response Data:');
    $('#result').append(data);
    $('#result').append('<br>');
    data=JSON.parse(data); 
    $('#textloanid').val(data.loan_type.load_id);
    $('#textloan_name').val(data.loan_type.loan_name);
    $('#result').prop('loan_id', data.loan_type.loan_id);
}
```

---

Changing `<input>` tags without ajax using jQuery:

```
$('#textloanid').val("YOUR_DESIRED_OUTPUT");
```

Comment: Thanks @roullie. I did data=JSON.parse(data); 
    $('#textloanid').val(data.load_id);
    $('#textloan_name').val(data.loan_name); still  not updating the form fields.

Comment: can you add the response data?

Comment: Thanks @roullie. i added response data sample on the post.thanks

Comment: `{"status":"success","loan_type":{"loan_id":"123","loan_name":"Bank Loan","description":"FRB Bank Loan","amount":"1250000","date":"2016-01-26","rate":"5.257"}}`  you are not getting this kind of response?

Comment: Thanks @roullie.yes i got such data,but not as response data.
after executing this php line
echo json_encode($array);
i got this.
{"status":"success","loan_type":{"loan_id":"123","loan_name":"Bank Loan","description":"FRB Bank Loan","amount":"1250000","date":"2016-01-26","rate":"15.62"}}

Comment: remove all unnecessary responses or `echo` 's just leave `json_encode($array);` so that te json response will be a valid one.  check also answer iv'e updated

Comment: Thanks @roullie. i remove all unnecessary responses or echo except for echo json_encode($array); and i realized that no data is coming from response data.I think i am missing something on the ajax function so that it can correctly handle json data.any clues? thanks

Comment: hmmm. can you try removing `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',` this line?

Comment: Thanks @roullie. i removed contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'.But dammn it still didn't work.my bad luck.thanks

Comment: :) can you try to see the developer `console` and `network`? we might be missing something.

Comment: Thanks @roullie. BTW, can you show me small ajax code that can change the <input tag>fileds directly without php.That could halp me to find whether problem is in ajax or in php side.Thanks for continuous and quick response.

Comment: `ajax` is a way to communicate to `php` from client side.  if you don't want to have `php` no need to use ajax.  check answer iv'e given an example.

Comment: Thanks @roullie.i follow your latest updates an did success: function(data) {   $('#textloanid').val("YOUR_DESIRED_OUTPUT");
$('#result').append('Response Data:');
$('#result').append(data);$('#json').val(data.loan_type.loan_name);
$('#result').prop('loan_id', data.loan_type.loan_id);
}, This really updates the input field.so it proves that php is not sending the  response data to 'success' function.Do i need any json header in php file? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your data after the query, create a new array and make a copy of each associative element in the original using a loop and once you see the element you wish to modify simply code the condition into the loop.  When the loop is done, you have a fresh array that meets your specs.  Also might want to unset the original after the copy is made to keep mem usage to a minimum.